# Expression to filter layer

Tags: qgis

QGIS 3.22

I have a layer imported into a geopackage from a DXF file. The geopackage is called roads.gpkg. The layer is called "polylines". "polylines" has an attribute "layer" (the name of the CAD layer the feature was on in the dxf file).

I wish to filter "polylines" to exclude features based on the value of "layer". I am using the Query Builder for the layer. So far I cannot get any expression to work. I have tried using just the WHERE clause, I have also tried using a full SQL statements. So far I have tried each of the following

```
select * from "polylines" where "layer" <> 'AA - Promap not required'

select * from "polylines" where "layer" = 'AA - Promap not required'

"layer" <> 'AA - Promap not required'    

"layer" = 'AA - Promap not required'

select * from "polylines"
```

None of the above expressions work. I include below an example screenshot of my expression as entered into the Query Builder. For all examples I get the error message as depicted in the second  screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong.

**EDIT 1**

I also tried

```
"fid"=1
```

Looking at the log message, the error is as follows:

> OGR[3] error 1: failed to prepare SQL: SELECT m."fid", m."geom",
> m."handle", m."block", m."etype", m."space", m."layer", m."olinetype",
> m."linetype", m."color", m."ocolor", m."color24", m."transparency",
> m."lweight", m."linewidth", m."ltscale", m."visible", m."width",
> m."thickness", m."ext" FROM "polylines" m WHERE
> "polylines_2587f7a9_d0c4_44e1_9872_290a556d0800"."layer" LIKE 'AA -
> Promap not required'

**EDIT 2**
I have uninstalled QGIS 3.22.11 and reinstalled 3.22.16. Initially, this resulted in the where clause filter working as a filter. Now it has stopped working again. Even layers with clauses that were wroking are now reporting the same error.

Comment: Did you already try `LIKE`?

Comment: Your expression as shown in the picture should work (there aren't really room for error). Did you try to restart QGIS / the whole computer ?

Comment: I wonder where this long table name comes `"polylines_2587f7a9_d0c4_44e1_9872_290a556d0800"."layer"`

Comment: QGIS allocates unique names to tables. I've also tried using this unique name in the query builder - same result. I'm currently uninstalling 3.22.11 and will reinstall 3.22.16 and try again

Comment: So I uninstalled 3.22.11 and reinstalled 3.22.16. That resolved issues for a few minutes. Now the same error is occurring!

Comment: Have you tried exporting the DXF to another file format?

Comment: @Erik It is now working inconsistently. I have isolated one reproducable error, which is if the layer is editable. I'm testing further to see if there are any other factors.

Answer (score 0):

I have uninstalled QGIS 3.22.11 and re-installed 3.22.16.

In 3.22.16 the error occurs when the layer is editable, regardless of whether changes have been committed (saved) or not.